# How to get version specific url in azure blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am storing my documents in azure blob storage with versioning enabled.
I noticed for all of the versions url is same,
I tried to pass versionid as a query string parameter,
but its saying invalid parameter.

[image]

Is there a way to get version specific url from azure blob storage

Version specific url

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you share the URL you are using?

Comment: @GauravMantri,I cant share the url as its  private,but i am trying to get version specific url...if we upload same file multiple times...then its versions will be created...but urls will be same..just need version specific docuemnt

Comment: To get a blob with specific version, the URL you would need to use would be something like the following: `https://account.blob.core.windows.net/container/blob?versionid=blob-version-id`. Are you using something like this?

Comment: @GauravMantri,Thanks for helping,I tried,but its giving <Error>
<Code>UnsupportedQueryParameter</Code>
<Message>One of the query parameters specified in the request URI is not supported. RequestId:bc0311b8-101e-0057-1a34-18eb2f000000 Time:2023-11-16T02:29:48.9622010Z</Message>
<QueryParameterName>versionid</QueryParameterName>
</Error>

Answer (score 0):

> Error> `UnsupportedQueryParameter` One of the query parameters specified in the request URI is not supported. RequestId:10951a2a-b01e-005c-5d6f-183b4e000000 Time:2023-11-16T09:28:00.0596573Z</ Message> < QueryParameterName >versionid</ QueryParameterName> < /Error>

The above error occurred due to when you were not passing the header in the request with **`x-ms-version`** in your environment.

When I used the same URI with passing header **`x-ms-version=2019-10-10`** in the postman I was able to fetch the specific version from the Azure blob storage.

**Request:**

```
GET  https://<storageaccount-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container-name>/<blobname>?versionid=<datetime>
Header:
x-ms-version=2019-10-10
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[Get Blob (REST API) - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob?tabs=microsoft-entra-id#uri-parameters)

Comment: what is the response for this...i guess it will be bytes of file...actually i needed a raw url...like when we upload a file..it generates a url...similary for a specific version id there any url

Comment: @Knowledge Apps When you request a specific version of a blob, the response will contain the content of that version of the blob. There is no separate URL generated for each version of the blob. Instead, you can use the same URL for the blob and pass the version ID as a query string parameter to retrieve a specific version of the blob.